# MySQL silent install fails

Tags: mysql, batch-file, windows-installer

I am trying to install mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi through batch file.

In the first step I try to unpack the manifest which gives me access to installer console. Passive install works alright however, if I try to install it quietly the batch file exits without unpacking the manifest.

Here is the 1st step batch file code:

```
@echo off 
color 0a
cls 
echo ========================================== 
echo MySQL Server - Installation - v.11/02/2015
echo ========================================== 
echo . 
echo . 
rem ------------------------------------------------ 
echo Installing MySQL (This may take a few minutes)
msiexec /i mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi /q /norestart /L*v "mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi.log"

echo Done.
```

Do anyone have a way around this error?

Comment: Are you saying that if you remove `/q` it runs fine?

Comment: what does the logfile say?

Comment: I am only able to run it when I replace /q with /passive. 

MySQL Installer shows UAC prompt and as silent install cannot address that. I don't think MySQL installer can work in silent mode.

I even tried running at higher privilege by having /a but that too doesn't work as MySQL Installer doesn't have administrative install.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter LOG file 
 Note: 1: 1729 
Product: MySQL Installer -- Configuration failed. Finally gave out 1603 error.

Comment: That's the final entry.  The real errors are above that.  You need to post it somewhere to read.

Comment: Found the solution, it was to do with wrong path. Check out my answer for details. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, found out that the log file was showing 1729 and  the next line showed configuration failed message.

Searching for error code 1729 in MySQL error codes. I found

```
Error: 1729 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_NO_SUCH_PARTITION)
Message: partition '%s' doesn't exist
```

Figured it may be as cmd was launching from System32. Adding %~dp0 (current directory) solved the issue.

I hope this may help others.

Answer (score 0):

`/q` may be raising an error since it's the the first character of user interface level options (`/qn` for example). Try using the full quiet option, `/quiet`

Comment: Tried all, Apparently the MySQL installer shows UAC prompt. Using silent mode doesn't work as UAC needs to be answered to.

MySQL doesn't support silent install it seems

Comment: I even lowering User Account Control to never notify. Still the problem persists /quiet doesn't work at all.